# Random call an event

Tags: vb.net, event-handling

I want to call a random PictureBoxN_Click event i have. How can I do this in vb.net?

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    If ListView1.Items.Count > 0 Then
        If IsNothing(Me.ListView1.FocusedItem) Then
            ListView1.TopItem.Selected = True
        End If
        For Each file As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
            Dim filePath As String = file.SubItems(1).Text & "\" & file.Text
            If file.Selected = True Then
                Process.Start(filePath)
            End If
        Next
    Else
        Dim rndm As Integer = CInt(Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * 20)) + 1
        Dim rndpic As String = "PictureBox" & rndm & "_Click"
        Call rndpic(Nothing, Nothing)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you really have **N** different handlers?...one for each PictureBox?  Or do you have **ONE** handler for all of them and need to pass the correct source PictureBox into it?

Comment: yes, i have **N** different handlers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I agree with jmcilhinney's answer, here is how to do what you originally asked for.  Note that this also shows you how to get a reference to the desired PictureBox, "by name", using Controls.Find().  We're using Reflection to find the matching method name and Invoke() it:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Static R As New Random
    Dim rndm As Integer = R.Next(1, 91) ' <-- return a value between 1 and 90 inclusive (yes, 91 is correct!)
    Dim ctlName As String = "PictureBox" & rndm.ToString
    Dim methodName As String = ctlName & "_Click"
    Dim flags As Reflection.BindingFlags = Reflection.BindingFlags.IgnoreCase Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Public Or Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic
    Dim MI As _MethodInfo = Me.GetType.GetMethod(methodName, flags)
    If Not IsNothing(MI) Then
        Dim matches() As Control = Me.Controls.Find(ctlName, True)
        If matches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matches(0) Is PictureBox Then
            Dim pb As PictureBox = DirectCast(matches(0), PictureBox)
            MI.Invoke(Me, New Object() {pb, New EventArgs})
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Good solution making use of reflection I might say

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you're not calling an event.  Events are raised and not by you.  The only simple way to raise a `Click` event on a `PictureBox` is to click it with the mouse.

What you're talking about is calling a method.  An event handler is not an event.  An event handler is a method that gets executed automatically when an event is raised.  Calling an event handler directly is really poor practice.

What you should be doing is putting the code that you want executed into its own method that has a parameter of type `PictureBox`.  You can then call that method from the `Click` event handler(s) of your `PictureBoxes` and from anywhere else you want as well.  If you do that then you don't have to even think about any `Click` events in this case and that's how it should be, because there is no clicking going on.

If you're doing the same thing for each `PictureBox` then there should only be one event handler for all the `PictureBoxes`.  If you want to execute the code for a random `PictureBox` when you click the `Button` then you pick a random `PictureBox` and pass it to the method.  E.g.

```
Private rng As New Random

Private Sub PictureBoxes_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox3.Click,
                                                                         PictureBox2.Click,
                                                                         PictureBox1.Click
    'Prcoess the PictureBox that was clicked.
    ProcessPictureBox(DirectCast(sender, PictureBox))
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Process a random PictureBox.

    Dim pictureBoxes = {PictureBox1, PictureBox2, PictureBox3}
    Dim pictureBox = pictureBoxes(rng.Next(pictureBoxes.Length))

    ProcessPictureBox(pictureBox)
End Sub

Private Sub ProcessPictureBox(pictureBox As PictureBox)
    'Use pictureBox here.
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of hard-coding the array of PictureBoxes, I'd find them "by name" using Controls.Find() (the recursive overload) in the Load() event and build that array **once**, storing it at class level.

Comment: @Idle_Mind, I guess you mean the `Load` event handler rather than the `Load` event. If I didn't want to hard-code the `PictureBoxes`, I would tend to call `Me.Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox)()` but I wouldn't do it in the `Load` event handler.  That array is only needed in that one method so its existing at the class level isn't really appropriate.  Any performance gain would barely measureable and certainly not noticeable, so maintaining appropriate scope should be the overriding consideration.

Comment: I agree with your comments on event handlers. I see too many ***just because you can do it does not mean you should***. IMO adding a little more info, calling an event handler directly though tightly couples the event handler to the calling code. If you want to change the event handler later, you could end up breaking that code and you'd have to check for all references to it. Testing then becomes more difficult too as tightly coupled code is inherently more difficult to separate into units. Event handlers ***should be made private and should only be exposed to other parts of the code***.

Comment: Not so sure about the scoping of the array (a List would be better) as there may be other routines that need to operate on all the PictureBoxes...maybe resetting them all to some state?  Also, I think the looping code would be less typing than hard-coding 20+ PictureBox names in to an array...maybe?  =)